# The default "delete selected" admin action in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

How can I remove or change the verbose name of the default admin action "delete selected X item" in the Django admin panel?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure if this sort of monkey-patching is a good idea, but shoving this in one of my `admin.py` works for me:

```
from django.contrib.admin.actions import delete_selected
delete_selected.short_description = u'How\'s this for a name?'
```

This will change the verbose name for *all* your admin sites. If you want to change it just for one particular model's admin, I think you'll need to write a [custom admin action](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/).

Tested with Django version 1.1:

```
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 1, 0, 'beta', 1)
```

Comment: seems a clever way for me it doesn't work. It simply removes the action box.

Comment: Huh. I tested it with Django 1.1 and it works fine. I put it right at the top (below the other import statements) of my admin.py.

Comment: it is (1 , 1, 0,'final', 0) for me, maybe thats the reason :(

Comment: Dominic & Hellnar: make sure to upgrade past 1.1.0, there was an urgent security fix with exploits in the wild. The problem was fixed in 1.1.1 and 1.0.4. Details here: http://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2009/oct/09/security/

Comment: I doubt it - I guessed at that idea by looking at the source for trunk (specifically http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/actions.py#L85).

Answer (score 23):

Alternatively to Googol's solution, and by waiting for delete_model() to [be implemented in current Django version](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.delete_model) , I suggest the following code.

It disables the default delete action for current AdminForm only.

```
class FlowAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['delete_model']

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
        del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions

    def delete_model(self, request, obj):
        for o in obj.all():
            o.delete()
    delete_model.short_description = 'Delete flow'

admin.site.register(Flow, FlowAdmin)
```

Comment: `delete_model` shouldn't be used, since this method is used when deleting one instance from the admin. In that case the queryset argument is not a queryset, it's a single instance, and it makes the loop crash.

Comment: This one should be selected as the accepted answser.

Comment: I'm using django 1.4.16 and `delete_model` seems to work in both cases (no exceptions or loops).

Answer (score 21):

You can disable the action from appearing with this code.

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.site.disable_action('delete_selected')
```

If you chose, you could then restore it on individual models with this:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['my_action', 'my_other_action', admin.actions.delete_selected]
```

Comment: Also using 'delete_selected' instead of admin.actions.delete_selected works fine in Django 1.6.

Answer (score 6):

For globally changing delete_selected's short_description [Dominic Rodger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20972/dominic-rodger)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565812/the-default-delete-selected-admin-action-in-django/1565857#1565857) seems best.

However for changing the short_description on the admin for a single model I think this alternative to [Stéphane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/554374/stephane)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565812/the-default-delete-selected-admin-action-in-django/4534773#4534773) is better:

```
def get_actions(self, request):
    actions = super().get_actions(request)
    actions['delete_selected'][0].short_description = "Delete Selected"
    return actions
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to replace delete_selected I do the following:

Copy the function `delete_selected` from `contrib/admin/actions.py` to your `admin.py` and rename it. Also copy the template `contrib/admin/templates/delete_selected_confirmation.html` to your template directory and rename it. Mine looks like this:

```
def reservation_bulk_delete(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    """
    Default action which deletes the selected objects.
    This action first displays a confirmation page whichs shows all the
    deleteable objects, or, if the user has no permission one of the related
    childs (foreignkeys), a "permission denied" message.

    Next, it delets all selected objects and redirects back to the change list.
    """
    opts = modeladmin.model._meta
    app_label = opts.app_label

    # Check that the user has delete permission for the actual model
    if not modeladmin.has_delete_permission(request):
        raise PermissionDenied

    # Populate deletable_objects, a data structure of all related objects that
    # will also be deleted.

    # deletable_objects must be a list if we want to use '|unordered_list' in the template
    deletable_objects = []
    perms_needed = set()
    i = 0
    for obj in queryset:
        deletable_objects.append([mark_safe(u'%s: <a href="%s/">%s</a>' % (escape(force_unicode(capfirst(opts.verbose_name))), obj.pk, escape(obj))), []])
        get_deleted_objects(deletable_objects[i], perms_needed, request.user, obj, opts, 1, modeladmin.admin_site, levels_to_root=2)
        i=i+1

    # The user has already confirmed the deletion.
    # Do the deletion and return a None to display the change list view again.
    if request.POST.get('post'):
        if perms_needed:
            raise PermissionDenied
        n = queryset.count()
        if n:
            for obj in queryset:
                obj_display = force_unicode(obj)

                obj.delete()

                modeladmin.log_deletion(request, obj, obj_display)
            #queryset.delete()
            modeladmin.message_user(request, _("Successfully deleted %(count)d %(items)s.") % {
                "count": n, "items": model_ngettext(modeladmin.opts, n)
            })
        # Return None to display the change list page again.
        return None

    context = {
        "title": _("Are you sure?"),
        "object_name": force_unicode(opts.verbose_name),
        "deletable_objects": deletable_objects,
        'queryset': queryset,
        "perms_lacking": perms_needed,
        "opts": opts,
        "root_path": modeladmin.admin_site.root_path,
        "app_label": app_label,
        'action_checkbox_name': helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME,
    }

    # Display the confirmation page
    return render_to_response(modeladmin.delete_confirmation_template or [
        "admin/%s/%s/reservation_bulk_delete_confirmation.html" % (app_label, opts.object_name.lower()),
        "admin/%s/reservation_bulk_delete_confirmation.html" % app_label,
        "admin/reservation_bulk_delete_confirmation.html"
    ], context, context_instance=template.RequestContext(request))
```

As you can see I commented out

```
queryset.delete()
```

and rather use:

```
obj.delete()
```

That's not optimal yet - you should apply something to the entire queryset for better performance.

In admin.py I disable the default action delete_selected for the entire admin site:

```
admin.site.disable_action('delete_selected')
```

Instead I use my own function where needed:

```
class ReservationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [reservation_bulk_delete, ]
```

In my model I define the `delete()` function:

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    def delete(self):
        self.status_server = RESERVATION_STATUS_DELETED
        self.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#disabling-a-site-wide-action

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.admin import sites
from django.contrib.admin.actions import delete_selected


class AdminSite(sites.AdminSite):
    """
    Represents the administration, where only authorized users have access.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AdminSite, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.disable_action('delete_selected')
        self.add_action(self._delete_selected, 'delete_selected')

    @staticmethod
    def _delete_selected(modeladmin, request, queryset):
        _delete_qs = queryset.delete

        def delete():
            for obj in queryset:
                modeladmin.delete_model(request, obj)
            _delete_qs()

        queryset.delete = delete
        return delete_selected(modeladmin, request, queryset)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class FooAdmin(sites.AdminSite):
        not_deleted = ['value1', 'value2']
        actions = ['delete_selected_values']

    def delete_selected_values(self, request, queryset):
        # my custom logic
        exist = queryset.filter(value__in=self.not_deleted).exists()
        if exist:
            error_message = "Error"
            self.message_user(request, error_message, level=messages.ERROR)
        else:
            delete_action = super().get_action('delete_selected')[0]
            return delete_action(self, request, queryset)
    delete_selected_values.short_description = 'delete selected'

admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, comment your code